# Why doesn't the ratio test work to evaluate this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\frac{k+5}{k+4}$$

$$
\frac{\ln\frac{k+6}{k+5}}{\ln\frac{k+5}{k+4}}
=\cdots
$$

(ln(k+6/k+5)/ln(k+5/k+4))

ln((k+6/k+5)*(k+4/k+5))

simplify

lim as k approaches infinity of ln(kˆ2 +10k +24/ kˆ2 +10k+25)= ln(1) = 0.

why doesn't the series converge?

Comment: But why **should** a ratio test always work?

Comment: How did you combine the two logarithms into one?

Comment: why wouldn't it always work?

Comment: natural log is on the numerator and denominator. is that not how it works?

Comment: $\ln\frac{a}{b}=\ln a-\ln b$, not $\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}$.

Comment: The ratio test is useful if you're dealing with factorials or things raised to the power of $n$, but it has its drawbacks. For example, the ratio test fails to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n$ diverges.

Comment: I reformatted it a little. Is what I entered what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the ratio test, if you consider $$a_k=\ln\frac{k+5}{k+4}$$ then $$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{\log \left(\frac{k+6}{k+5}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{k+5}{k+4}\right)}=\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{k+5}\right)}{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{k+4}\right)}$$ Now, use that, for small values of $y$, $$\log(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ Make  $y=\frac{1}{k+5}$ for the numerator, $y=\frac{1}{k+4}$ for the denominator, use the long division to arrive to $$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=1-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{11}{2 k^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^3\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

With equivalents (we can use equivalents because we have a series with positive termes): $$\ln \Bigl(\dfrac{k+5}{k+4}\Bigr)=\ln\Bigl(1+\dfrac 1{k+4}\Bigr)\sim_{+\infty} \dfrac 1{k+4}\sim_{+\infty} \dfrac 1k .$$
The series  has  a general term equivalent to the general term of the harmonic series, which diverges, hence it diverges.